# Invalid Model State with ViewModel - C# ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Hopefully a basic question, I've created a "Create" page for Contacts which creates a list of all Customers in the system. I use a ViewModel to do this and this has been fine. However now on the Customers model I've assigned the CustomerName field to be Required it's causing a ModelState.IsValid to be false, and I cannot figure out why.

Customer

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Customer Name")]
        public string? CustomerName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    }
```

Contact

```
public class Contact
    {
        public int ContactId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
    public class ContactDetailViewModel
    {
        public Contact Contact { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Customers { get; set; }
    }
```

Form

```
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.EmailAddress" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.EmailAddress" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.EmailAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Contact.Telephone" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contact.Telephone" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.Telephone" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Customer.CustomerName" class="control-label"></label>
                <select class="form-control dropdown" asp-for="Customer.CustomerId" asp-items="@Model.Customers">
                    <option></option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Customer.CustomerId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ContactId,FirstName,LastName,EmailAddress,Telephone")] Contact contact, ContactDetailViewModel contactDetailViewModel)
        {
            contact.Customer = await _context.Customers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CustomerId == contactDetailViewModel.Customer.CustomerId);
            //Has to be a better way of doing this??? Why is it faling without... 06/03/2021
            //ModelState.Remove("Customer.CustomerName");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(contact);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(contact);
        }
```

If I don't include ModelState.Remove("Customer.CustomerName"); then it doesn't work. However I don't want to be doing anything with the CustomerName as I just want to update the Contact.Customer to be the "new" selected customer.

Thanks!

Comment: your `Customer.CustomerName` is not bound at all, what you bind instead is the `Customer.CustomerId` :). So the client-side validation is even passed. The validation error for `CustomerName` is also for `CustomerId` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the error in your class. Add CustomerId to Contact:

```
public class Contact
    {
        public int ContactId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public int  CustomerId { get; set; }
        public virtual  Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

and fix the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Customer.CustomerName" class="control-label"></label>
                <select class="form-control dropdown" asp-for="Contact.CustomerId" asp-items="@Model.Customers">
                    <option></option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Contact.CustomerId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

and you can fix action too:

```
 contact.Customer = await _context.Customers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CustomerId == contactDetailViewModel.Contact.CustomerId);
```

but it is a reduntant code. You don't need this code at all, since you can save Contact without this.

and you need to fix the binding too by adding CustomerId:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ContactId, CustomerId, FirstName,LastName,EmailAddress,Telephone")] Contact contact, ContactDetailViewModel contactDetailViewModel)
```

and by the way you include the whole Customer in the model only for

```
  <label asp-for="Customer.CustomerName" class="control-label"></label>
```

you can leave Customer property null and use this code:

```
  <label asp-for="Contact.CustomerId" class="control-label"> Customer </label>
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much. I had to also make a change to the LINQ query on the Create action to use Contact.CustomerId instead of Customer.ContactId but I believe that's fine?

Comment: @DanielHill it's strange that this code works for you, it is not even related to the ***required value*** of `CustomerName`. Of course what you need may be `CustomerId` but as long as your view model has `CustomName` as ***required***, that value should be bound as well. So don't tell me that this `<label asp-for="Customer.CustomerName"` is what binds the `CustomerName` - It's just a label. Again, please confirm that you ***actually removed*** the `[Required]` applied on `CustomerName` - otherwise it cannot work. I see this so confusing.

Comment: @Hopeless  Contact instnce is saved not the Customer one. CustomerName has hothing to do with this at all since Contact has only CustomerId that is selected from the dropdown list.

Comment: @Sergey are you sure? look carefully again at the class `Customer` in the OP's question. Do you see the `[Required]` applied on the `CustomerName`. This view model `ContactDetailViewModel` is bound (in the `Create` method), that means the whole view model's graph is bound including the `ContactDetailViewModel.Customer`. So if `CustomerName` is not bound, the validation would fail (***exactly as what he described in the question***). And I don't see you even mentioned for ***why he got that error***. Why? Could you explain now?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I added CostumerId to the binding. But I am a professional and don't pay much attention to these details. IMHO it is not worth mentioning it will be fixed by default.

Comment: No actually your `CustomerId` is related to another view model (the `Contact`), not the `ContactDetailViewModel` which is what causes the original issue. You might try to solve ***another issue*** that I don't care. But here, obviously not related to what the user asked in his question. That's why I feel it strange. I doubt that somehow the OP ***accidentally*** removed the `[Required]` attribute  and ***at the same time*** applied your code and he just saw it worked. He might have more than 1 problem here.

Comment: Ok , just for you I added some more code. But it is not a code review forum . All this code out of the scope of the question. There much more improvement that can be done. But I have to answer the question only. All another stuff is just a waste of time.

Comment: I personally cannot stand seeing confusing things like this and I do want the OP to take his responsibility to make it clear. Actually what you solved for the OP is not much related to what causes the ***described*** error on his side.  You could have focused on that error as the ***main problem*** and might extend more on some other issue that you could spot. There are a lot of users of the same kind as the OP here on SO and really in many cases we're just speechless. Almost hopeless because of the questions' quality being degraded year after year.